# How can I get one process modules cache in node.js?

Tags: node.js, process

I run a node.js process, where is the module cache?
How can I get this process's module cache?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if you have to store values in cache then node-redis module is best for you. 
Redis is a fast and efficient in-memory key-value store. It is also known as a data structure server, as the keys can contain strings, lists, sets, hashes and other data structures. 

var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); 
client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});
client.set('framework', 'AngularJS', function(err, reply) {
  console.log(reply);
});
client.get('framework', function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```